# Do the elliptic curves over prime fields must always contain prime number of elements (prime order)?

Tags: elliptic-curves, finite-field

I have gone through one example where i saw a curve defined over some prime number containing non-prime order.

Comment: You've just seen an example of a curve over a prime field which has non-prime order, and your question is whether they exist? How could you have found one if they don't?

Comment: Don't you think you just answered your own question?

Comment: Montgomery and Edwards curves can't have a prime order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, an elliptic curve over $\mathbb{F}_p$ can have a nonprime order. 
Much more is known.

As mentioned in Stinson's book Cryptography:Theory and Practice, 2nd Edition, Theorem 6.1, the additive group of an Elliptic curve $E$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$ with $p>3,$ and prime, is isomorphic to $Z_{n_1}\times Z_{n_2}$ with $$n_2|n_1,\quad n_2|(p-1).$$